# ksh get exit status in assignment

Tags: shell, ksh

I need to know the exit status of command that do assignment.

```
export VALUE=`My_Get_Value 10`
```

I need to know the exit status of My_Get_Value script.

In the **$?** I have the status of assignment itself.

I need it in KSH v93

Comment: What does `t=\`echo t; false\`; echo "$t:$?"` output?

Comment: I found that if I remove the export the $? will get the exit status of script.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I was not aware that `export` did that. Though I suppose it makes sense. You should probably add that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 5):

`export VALUE=$(My_Get_Value 10)` is not an assignment statement; it is a call to the `export` command, which takes arguments that *look* like assignment statements. The easiest fix is to separate the assignment from the call to `export`.

```
VALUE=$(My_Get_Value 10)
mgv_exit=$?
export VALUE
```

It doesn't matter if you call `export` before or after the assignment (as long as you don't call it between the assignment and saving the value of `$?`), since `export` sets an attribute on the *name* `VALUE`, not the value of the parameter named `VALUE`. The following is identical:

```
export VALUE
VALUE=$(My_Get_Value 10)
mgv_exit=$?
```