# variable assignment in shell script

Tags: shell, variable-assignment

Our directory structure looks like

```
/long/dir/name/bin/exec.sh
/long/dir/name/logs
/long/dir/name/input
/long/dir/name/output.
```

in exec.sh I want to retrieve the root directory (`/long/dir/name` in this case), store this in a variable so I can use it to refer to `$DIR/output`, `$DIR/input` etc.

I got as far as [exec.sh]:

```
#!/bin/sh
export DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )" | sed -e 's,/*[^/]\+/*$,,'
echo "$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )" | sed -e 's,/*[^/]\+/*$,,'
echo "My Dir: '$DIR'"
```

This outputs:

```
/long/dir/name   <-- Which is what I want
My Dir: ''
```

What is going wrong when assigning it to the DIR variable?

Comment: ...mind you, using a pipeline (involving sed?!) for this is silly (inefficient, hard-to-read, error-prone); fixing John's advice to use `$BASH_SOURCE` rather than `$0` makes more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the "what went wrong" question.

You stuck the pipe to `sed` *outside* the subshell for the assignment (and technically `export var=...` isn't an assignment it is a call to `export` (see [ksh get exit status in assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26784959/258523) as an example of this).

Anyway, what happens on that first line therefore is the shell sees

`export DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"` `|` `sed -e 's,/*[^/]\+/*$,,'`

(note the whitespace around the pipe there). And pipelines execute in sub-shells so your `export` is happening in a su-shell and then being lost.

Stick the `sed` in the sub-shell and you fix the problem.

```
export DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd | sed -e 's,/*[^/]\+/*$,,')"
```

Comment: You're right about the direct problem with the original code, but it's still way more complicated than it needs to be (see my answer).

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this:

```
DIR=${BASH_SOURCE%/*/*}
```

That is, strip the last two path parts from the script's own path, and use that.  Run it through `realpath` or `readlink -f` if you need to get a canonical path.

Comment: If you are going to suggest `readlink` it might be better to just suggest `readlink $path/../..` and let readlink do the work.

Comment: @John DIR=${0%/*/*} gives me 'exec.sh'?

Comment: `${BASH_SOURCE%/*/*}`, rather. `$0` isn't a good fit for this use -- as @drjerry's issue above demonstrates.

Comment: `echo ${BASH_SOURCE%/*/*}` in exec.sh still gives ./exec.sh?